# Is it possible to create Drawable object using Path object?

Tags: android-canvas, android-drawable

Is there any way to create `Drawable` using PathData ? for example here is a CheckMark Path `"M6,11 l3.5,4 l8,-7"`. I want to convert this path data to Drawable image.

I've successfully created `BitmapDrawable` using below code:

```
val pathStr: String = "M6,11 l3.5,4 l8,-7"
val pathData: Path = PathParser.createPathFromPathData(pathStr)
val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(24,24, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
val paint = Paint().apply { color = color }
canvas.drawPath(pathData, paint)
val bitmapDrawable: Drawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)
```

Here the `bitmapDrawable` is `BitmapDrawable`. But I need `Drawable`. Because, `Drawable` can scale up as much as possible but `Bitmap` cannot (the quality will be degraded when scaled up).

Comment: It seems to me that you could take your path data and replace the path data in a vector drawable that is substantially like what you want. I can't say offhand if the path data in your program would match what is needed to path data in a vector drawable, but you can check that out. [Here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-androids-vector-image-format-vectordrawable-ab09e41d5c68) is an introduction to the nuts and bolts of vector drawables that I have found helpful.